# How to set Mongodb

Tags: centos, mongodb

I'm trying to set up Mongodb on my vps but when trying to start it:

`service mongod start`

It returns this error:

```
Starting mongod: /usr/bin/mongod: error while loading shared libraries: 
libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                               [FAILED]
```

From what I read Mongodb runs on c++, so I've installed:

```
Installed:
  gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.6-4.el6                                                  

Dependency Installed:
  libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.6-4.el6
```

But I still get the error.
Maybe it doesn't have permission.
(Running Centos 6.3 64bit)

Ps: I'm an newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `libstdc++` to satisfy that dependency

So `yum install libstdc++` should do the trick.

Comment: `Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * epel: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * extras: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * rpmforge: mirror.rit.edu
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.org
Setting up Install Process
Package libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: Curious then.
How did you install MongoDB? It is not included in the standard RHEL/CentOS packages.

Comment: `yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server`

Comment: [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/)

Comment: If you have used the proper repo ie the x86_64 to install MongoDB then maybe it is a problem with the rpm. Can't readily test it atm to see if I get similar results. 
I assume you are executing all commands as root. Also just to be on the safe side execute locate libstdc++.so.6 . It should return as a result where that library is located

Comment: Oh god ... I think I've got it.

Comment: I removed the installed yum packages and they actually were installed as 32bit, installing now as 64bit.

Comment: A issue: when going for install it want's to install the i686 (32bit) packages again. Not the one I've specified baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64